# ui-bootstrap dropdown is not working with ui-bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a scenario in which I have to trigger a modal with two different buttons. One button is working fine with Modal Popup but the other button which is inside **ui-bootstrap** drop down is not triggering the modal popup until I trigger from other button.
So far i figured out that the controller is not loading unless i click it from button which is outside drop down.

the code for opening the popup is follows

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/pages/teams/events/event-modal.html',
    controller: 'EventModalController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
      data: function () {
        var obj = {
          clubs: vm.clubs,
          mode: mode,
          selectedEvent: vm.selectedEvent,
        }
        return obj;
      }
    }
  });
  modalInstance.result.then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);

  }, function () {
    return null;
  });
```

The buttons for triggering this popup is

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-single-button">
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="javascript:;" ui-sref="root.teams.dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li role="menuitem"><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="vm.createEvent('edit')">Add Team</a></li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: can you provide us your code?

Comment: I think the problem comes from modal and drop down 's z-index. check their  z-index and modify it or provide your code for us